# DAX Formula to Sum by a "hidden" group / field

Tags: excel, pivot, dax

I have a table with the following data:

| Customer | Category | Product | Color | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Alpha | CC | Blue | 200 |
| A | Alpha | RI | Red | 100 |
| B | Alpha | CC | Blue | 100 |
| B | Alpha | FA | Blue | 50 |
| B | Alpha | RI | Red | 100 |
| C | Alpha | EL | Blue | 200 |

I would like to summarize the data in an excel pivot, by all the columns except the 'customer', like this:

| Category | Product | Color | Sum of Quantity | Quantity_Customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | CC | Blue | 300 | 550 |
| Alpha | EL | Blue | 200 | 200 |
| Alpha | FA | Blue | 50 | 250 |
| Alpha | RI | Red | 200 | 550 |

The measure 'Quantity_Customer' should show the total quantity of all 'customers' which have the appropriate category/product/color.

For example:
The value of the measure 'Quantity_Customer' in the first line should be 550, since customer A (with a total quantity of 300) and customer B (with a total quantity of 250) both have the Article Alpha/CC/Blue (category/product/color).

I tried the following DAX:
`=CALCULATE(SUM(Table5[Quantity]);ALLEXCEPT(Table5;Table5[Customer]))`

But this only works, when the customer is displayed as column in the table (pivot).
Otherwise the value of 'Quantity_Customer' is always displayed as 750.

Is there a way, to sum the quantity by customer, even if this field is "hidden"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I calculated the sum of the quantity for each customer identified by the outer SUMX function and keeping the context of all other columns except Customer. The ALLEXCEPT will remove the filters from all columns except the specified ones keeping the Customer context intact. T

```
   Quantity_Customer = 
    SUMX(
        VALUES(Table5[Customer]), 
        CALCULATE(
            SUM(Table5[Quantity]), 
            ALLEXCEPT(Table5, Table5[Customer])
        )
    )
```

[image]